# Why reducer does not work correctly in my case?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

why "set" just has one element while for example it should have 4 elements for first 5 lines of input that have the same URL and four different IP. I also used "for-each" instead of "iterator" but does not work. can someone help me?

mapper

```
public class WordCount {

    public static class TokenizerMapper extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, Text> {

        private Text IP = new Text();
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            String[] tokens = line.split(",");
            word.set(tokens[2]);
            IP.set(tokens[0]);
            context.write(word, IP);
        }
    }
```

reducer

```
    public static class IntSumReducer extends Reducer<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
            Iterator<Text> iterator = values.iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                set.add(iterator.next().toString());
            }
            int a = set.size();
            String str = String.format("%d", a);
            context.write(key, new Text(str));
        }
    }
```

job

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
        job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);       
    }
}
```

input

```
"10.131.0.1","[29/Nov/2017:14:31:33","GET / HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.2","[29/Nov/2017:14:31:38","GET / HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.3","[29/Nov/2017:14:31:56","GET / HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.4","[29/Nov/2017:14:32:02","GET / HTTP/1.1","404"
"10.131.0.5","[29/Nov/2017:16:31:39","GET / HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.1","[29/Nov/2017:14:05:35","GET /contest.php HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.2","[29/Nov/2017:14:05:38","GET /contest.php HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.3","[29/Nov/2017:14:05:50","GET /contest.php HTTP/1.1","404"
"10.131.0.1","[29/Nov/2017:13:51:41","GET /login.php HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.2","[29/Nov/2017:13:51:49","GET /login.php HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.1","[29/Nov/2017:13:51:46","GET /contestproblem.php?name=RUET%20OJ%20Server%20Testing%20Contest HTTP/1.1","200"
"10.131.0.8","[29/Nov/2017:13:51:46","GET /contestproblen.php?name=RUET%20OJ%20Server%20Testing%20Contest HTTP/1.1","200"
```

my result is

```
"GET / HTTP/1.1"    1
"GET /contest.php HTTP/1.1" 1
"GET /contestproblem.php?name=RUET%20OJ%20Server%20Testing%20Contest HTTP/1.1"  1
"GET /contestproblen.php?name=RUET%20OJ%20Server%20Testing%20Contest HTTP/1.1"  1
"GET /login.php HTTP/1.1"   1
```

Comment: Can you add some logging and look at what exactly is being written to `set`? Also, in your reducer you convert values from `Text` -> `String` which is inefficient. Just make a `Set<Text>`.

Comment: I set an string before going to iterator. and instead of **set.add(iterator.next().toString());** i wrote **str += iterator.next.toString() + ",";** and then i write it in context as a value. and i got all IPs that are related to a key

Comment: i think just **+=** operator works in reducer when working with iterator of values

Comment: I need logging added to `set` to help further. At the very least can you emit the value as `new Text(set.toString())` and look at that?

Comment: Its like below but why

Comment: "GET /login.php HTTP/1.1" [["10.131.0.2", "10.131.0.1"]]

Comment: and how can i correct it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Reducer is working fine, but the Combiner is not doing what you think. What's happening with the Combiner turned on is:

MAPPER OUTPUT:

```
("GET / HTTP/1.1", "10.31.0.1")
("GET / HTTP/1.1", "10.31.0.2")
```

COMBINER INPUT:

```
("GET / HTTP/1.1", {"10.31.0.1", "10.31.0.2"})
```

COMBINER OUTPUT:

```
("GET / HTTP/1.1", "2") //You have the right answer here...
```

REDUCER INPUT:

```
("GET / HTTP/1.1", {"2"}) //...but then it gets passed into the Reducer again
```

REDUCER OUTPUT:

```
("GET / HTTP/1.1", "1")
```

Only one element enters the Reducer, and so it reduces down to "1".

Remove the Combiner (delete `job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);` and this will work.

Other recommended changes:

1. Have the Reducer output `IntWritable` instead of converting a number to `Text`.
2. Make the `Set` a `Set<Text>` instead of `Set<String>`, in order to save expensive `Text -> String` conversions.